# constructing a 2D array and assigning

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

```
package homework3;

public class DoubleMatrix
{

   private double[][] doubMatrix;

   public DoubleMatrix (int row, int col)
   {
    if(row > 0 & col > 0)
    {
        makeDoubMatrix(1,1);
    }
    else
    {
        row = 1;
        col = 1;
    }

}
public DoubleMatrix(double[][] tempArray)
{   
    int k = tempArray.length;
    if(tempArray != null)
    {


        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(k== tempArray[i].length)
            {


            }

        }   
     }
    else
    {
        makeDoubMatrix(1,1);
    }

}


}
```

This is what i was supposed to start my assignment with: 
 Write a class called DoubleMatrix in which you declare a 2-dim. array of doubles (I'm calling it doubMatrix) as a private instance variable. Include the following constructors or instance methods (NO static METHODS HERE):

- constructor with an int for the first dimension (be sure it's > 0, set to 1 if not), and an int for the second dimension (be sure it's > 0, set to 1 if not) and call the makeDoubMatrix private instance method (see below)
- another constructor with a 2-dim. array of doubles as its parameter (assign if parameter isn't null AND if each row has the same length as the other rows), otherwise, call makeDoubMatrix with 1, 1)

can someone check that if I did the check in second constructor right? Also I left out the assigning statement in the second if because I don't know what to assign can anyone tell me what to assign since the problem only say assign but didn't say to assign to what value.

Comment: You have several problems in your code, in BOTH constructors.  More importantly, asking for a code-review is off-topic for SO.  There's another site, [codereview.se] that is intended for this type of question. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for more information on what is expected on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to check for each row first, whether they are of same length or not. You can maintain a `boolean flag` variable, which you can set to `false` as soon as you see that the current row is not the same length as the next row.

You can try the below code, and test whether it works: -

```
public DoubleMatrix(double[][] tempArray)
{   
    if(tempArray != null)
    {
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length - 1;i++)
        {   
            // Check each row with the next row
            if(tempArray[i].length != tempArray[i + 1].length)
            {
                 // as you find the row length not equal, set flag and break
                 flag = false;
                 break;
            }
        }   
        if (flag) {
            doubleMatrix = tempArray;
        } else {
            makeDoubleMatrix(1,1);
        }
     } else {
        makeDoubleMatrix(1, 1);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public DoubleMatrix(double[][] tempArray)
{   
    //Calling tempArray.length if tempArray is null will get you an error
    if(tempArray != null)
    {


        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<tempArray[i].length;j++)
               {
                      doubleMatrx[i][j] = tempArray[i][j];
               }

        }   
     }
    else
    {
        makeDoubMatrix(1,1);
    }

}
```

Also in Java a 2D array will always have the same number of columns in each row since it's declaration is something like `int bob[][] = new int[a][b]`

Comment: there isn't a check if each row has the same length as the other rows

Comment: @DanielHu. Sure you can have a 2D array with different number of columns in each row, in Java. You just have to leave the 2nd size parameter blank, and assign it inside the outer loop.